# Flutter: How to theme material widgets in Cupertino theme?

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino, flutter-theme

I have a Flutter app which uses Material theme for Android and Cupertino theme for iOS. But I use `Card` widget, which is a Material widget, in both themes. Now I have the following code in `main.dart`

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => PlatformProvider(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => PlatformApp(
            cupertino: (_, __) => CupertinoAppData(
                theme: CupertinoThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light, ...)),
            material: (_, __) => MaterialAppData(
                theme: ThemeData(
                  brightness: Brightness.light,
                  primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
                  cardTheme: CardTheme(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    ...
                  )
                  ...
                ),),
......
```

As you can see, the `Card` widget is themed using `cardTheme` in the Material `ThemeData`, but there is no corresponding `cardTheme` in `CupertinoThemeData`. So on iOS the `Card`s only use their default theme.

So how do I theme Material widgets like `Card` in Cupertino theme?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Faced the same issue I tried to play with `MaterialBasedCupertinoThemeData` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialBasedCupertinoThemeData-class.html but it doesn't respect the dark theme properly. Eventually, I've found a solution how to combine MaterialTheme with CupertinoTheme at the same time and apply dark/light theming correctly:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final Brightness platformBrightness = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.platformBrightness;
  return Theme(
    data: ThemeData(brightness: platformBrightness),
    child: CupertinoApp(
      theme: CupertinoThemeData(
        brightness: platformBrightness,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this implementation handle theme transitions smoothly? I thought you need CupertinoDynamicColor to do that.